# SQLite Query with two where clauses

Tags: android

I need to update my SQLite database's table.

Table consists of AppName (String) ,StartTime (String) and EndTime (String) columns.

I need to update EndingTime of a record  where AppName = app(Variable containing present app's name) AND EndingTime != "0".

Single Where clause was working fine, but I do not know a standard procedure for including two where clauses. I tried in the following way, but no result.

```
return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, "AppName=? AND EndingTime<>?", new String[]{AppName,"0"})>0
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AND EndingTime != "0"
```

I'm not sure if you are referring to the EndingTime supplied in a method, say:

```
public static void updateEndingTime (final Context context, 
    String appName, int endingTime) {}
```

Or if you mean the EndingTime already stored in the database for that app name.

On the first case, simply do an if statement before updating the database, such as if the endingTime supplied is different then zero, you save the value, otherwise you don't:

```
public static void updateEndingTime (final Context context, 
    String appName, int endingTime) {
    //open your database object, blah, blah

    if (endingTime != 0) {
        //save the data
    }
}
```

If it's the second case, then simply merge the two with the 'And' word.

```
public static int updateEndingTime (final Context context, 
    String appName, int endingTime) {
    //open your database object, blah, blah
    String where = "AppName = " + appName + " and EndingTime != 0 ";
    return mDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, where, null);
}
```

Make sure that `args` is a properly structured ContentValues object.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was the second case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ALTER TABLE** function on your onUpgrade() method.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
   // If you need to add a column
   if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
       db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN new_column INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess you misunderstood my question. I Need to update a column named EndingTime. Column is already present in the table structure. While inserting, I'm inserting "0" as EndingTime. When I get the EndingTime I need to update this "0" with the present value.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **!=** instead of **<>** .

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is right apart from the fact that you should be using != instead of <>. When I need two WHERE clauses in my sql statement, I join them by AND as well. There is no harm in doing that. It will not expose your query to SQL injection attacks anyway because of the fact that you are using parameterized query.

Comment: The following code is not working too!!
db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, "(AppName=? AND EndingTime!=?)", new String[]{AppName,"0"})